# Cassandra sort not by primary key

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I'm trying to model a table in Cassandra, I'm quite new and stumbled upon one problem. I've got the following:

```
CREATE TABLE content_registry (
    service text,
    file text,
    type_id tinyint,
    container text,
    status_id tinyint,
    source_location text,
    expiry_date timestamp,
    modify_date timestamp,
    create_date timestamp,
    to_overwrite boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY ((service), file, type_id)
);
```

So as I understand:

- `service` is my partition key and based on this value hashes will be generated and values will be split in cluster
- `file` is clustering key
- `type_id` is clustering key
- These three bodies combine a composite (compound) primary key

What I've figured out is that whenever I'll insert new data, Cassandra will upsert (either insert or update if the value with that compound primary key exists)

Now what I'm struggling is, that I want my data to come back sorted by `create_date` in descending order, however `create_date` is not part of primary key.

If I add `create_date` to my primary key, I won't be able to upsert data, because `create_date` means timestamp when record was inserted, so if I add it to primary key every time there's an insert, I'll end up with multiple records.

What are the other options? Order in application? That doesn't seem very efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I've figured out is that whenever I'll insert new data, Cassandra
>   will upsert (either insert or update if the value with that compound
>   primary key exists)

Totally right.

> Now what I'm struggling is, that I want my data to come back sorted by
>   create_date in descending order, however create_date is not part of
>   primary key.
>   If I add create_date to my primary key, I won't be able to upsert
>   data, because create_date means timestamp when record was inserted, so
>   if I add it to primary key every time there's an insert, I'll end up
>   with multiple records.

With these sentences you are actually contradicting.

If `create_date` isn't part of your key but a property and the data is upserted, it means that the records are always the same. Therefore when querying by the key and fetching `create_date` you always have the latest. If you actually want to have the date when the record got *created* you should just not override the data anymore after the first time you inserted that record.

If it's the case you want to represent a series of data, you indeed need to avoid upserting, this is could be done by using `create_date` as additional partition key. I'd rather prefeer using `time_uuid` which comes with quite handy functions.

Last but not least, the most interesting question is, what actually the usecase is that you want to reflect. When modelling data in cassandra you always should know your queries you need to run in advance.

Comment: It's a content sync service. I've written a small piece of database code to support their data model without much questioning. And now I'd like to move this to Cassandra as a first NoSQL step in our company. I'll revisit requirements and try to adjust them for Cassandra model

Answer (score 3):

The key concept in Cassandra is that you have to decide what's your `PRIMARY KEY`, that is what in your rows can be *unique* and *known* at query times. This is a very basic requirement, since failing at recognizing this will lead to a bad model.

From what I can see, you identified `service` as your PARTITION KEY, so I'm thinking that this field is what "rules" your data. This is something you **must** really know to perform even a single query (ignoring the inefficient table scan `SELECT * FROM content_registry;`). Within each `service`, you currently have your rows ordered by `file` and then by `type_id`. I don't know the exact meaning of the latter field, but you can currently have two rows identified by `('service1', 'a.jpg', 1)` and `('service1', 'a.jpg', 2)`. So if `type_id` is somehow related to the `file`, the model is a bit incorrect.

Now, assuming you want to fetch the same records for each `service` in another order, what you really need to do is create another table that will include the `create_date` as the first clustering column, eg `(service, create_date, file, type_id)`. This will allow you to fetch records ordered by creation date, and when two records are created in the same date, they will be further ordered by `file`, and then by `type_id`.

A second approach is to attach a secondary index to the `create_date` field of your original table. This will allow to query by creation date.

A third approach, probably better than the second, is the use of a Materialized View. It will hide a lot of burdens for you and will probably scale better than secondary indexes.

Please note that having secondary indexes or materialized views usually don't scale well. Check if these approaches are enough for your use case.

Comment: `type_id` is just a enum, which might be `Container`, `Content`, `Folder`. Now I've just looked at actual data and it seems that `Service` and `Name` are always unique, so `type_id` doesn't seem to be part PRIMARY KEY at all. I think I'll have to revisit data model and try to adapt it for Cassandra.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas What's the field `Name`? Do you mean `file`?

Comment: Yes sorry. I've just copied names from SQL Server instance, instead of Cassandra. `service` and `file` are right names. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> If I add create_date to my primary key, I won't be able to upsert data.

Why not? Suppose your key was `PRIMAY KEY (service, create_date, file, type_id)`? That will let you sort by `create_date` **for each service** but not globally.

If you want to do it globally (that is, you want all services and all files sorted by create date) then things are probably more complex if you still want to be able to shard your data. One option would be to make the primary key `PRIMARY KEY (create_date, service, file, type_id)` and use one of the [order preserving partitioners](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Partitioners).

Also, a bit more information here: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/we-shall-have-order

Comment: Perhaps I should've been more clear on my question. Each time there's a new record inserted, it will have current timestamp as a value. so let's say if I insert values like `('service1', '2017-01-09 19:35:33', 'fileName1', 1)` and then `('service1', '2017-01-09 19:35:34', 'fileName1', 1)`, I'll end up with two records, because these are primary keys and they are different, right? What I'd like to have is to keep just the latest record. I'll edit.

Comment: If you only want to have the latest record, excluding the timestamp, the timestamp shouldn't be part of your key.

Comment: @questionare I understand that, but I also need to have data sorted by that timestamp, that's why I said _If I add create_date to my primary key, I won't be able to upsert data_ :). Seems that sorting at application level is go-to option.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas yeah most probably yes. With Cassandra in the end it is a bit different than with SQL. You should model your data by the queries your app/client will have. The question actually is what you want to query for?! On the one hand you obviously want to query for records by `((service), file, type_id)`, so what's the actual requirement you want to serve with `created_at`?

Comment: @questionare That was just the requirement from other software devs to retrieve those records in this order, I cannot recall the exact reason why they needed it like that, I'll try to ask them once more why it's like that.